# ng-select Angular 2+ change model view

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I'm using the ng-select component for my angular 5 app. [ng-select component](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select)
I want to change the view component. In multiple select, I want to print the number of components rather than listing the ones selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the examples :

```
<ng-select
        [items]="people$1 | async"
        [multiple]="true"
        [closeOnSelect]="false"
        bindLabel="name"
        placeholder="Select people"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople1">
</ng-select>

<p>Number of selected persons : {{selectedPeople1.length}}</p>
```

Comment: I want to print the length inside the ng-select component's view

Comment: You are supposed to use a library, not change it. If you want to change it, then you must create your own library.